BG95 error after getting GPS can't reconnect to network
I'm encountering an issue with obtaining the GPS location in my application. When I fail to get the GPS location, my error handling mechanism attempts to use LBS commands via Queclocator as a fallback. However, Queclocator relies on the HTTP protocol, and when I query the LBS location, it returns "+QLBS: 707," indicating that the HTTP(S) network open failed. It seems that anything related to HTTP is not functioning correctly. After querying the GPS location, I use the QGPSEND command to end the GPS session. Subsequently, I try to reopen the PDP context, but this action results in an ERROR. I'm seeking assistance to resolve these issues with HTTP protocol handling and reopening the PDP context.
To resolve the issue, I attempted several approaches. First, I ensured that the PDP context was correctly configured and active before initiating the LBS commands. I also verified that the device had proper network connectivity and sufficient signal strength. Additionally, I tried resetting the network settings and re-establishing the PDP context after sending the QGPSEND command. Despite these efforts, I still encountered the same HTTP(S) network open failure and the subsequent error when reopening the PDP context. The only workaround that temporarily resolves the issue is restarting the modem, which restores HTTP functionality and allows successful querying of the LBS location using Queclocator. However, I need a more permanent solution and am seeking further guidance to diagnose and fix the problem.

QuecLocator is no longer supported by Quectel BG95. Underlying request can not succeed anymore.
